# Images get interlaced when using camera2 API

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, camera2, interlacing

I'm trying to create an app using the camera2 api, what I need is to create a burst of 30 fps which I was able to create.

The problems is both the preview images and the saved images interlaced (I'm photographing some blinking leds so its easy to see).
I tried to disable the auto exposure and set the sensitivity myself but that didn't work.

```
 private void captureStillPicture() {
    try {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        mPictureCounter = 0;
        if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {
            return;
        }

        List<CaptureRequest> captureList = new ArrayList<CaptureRequest>();

        // This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture.
        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);

        // Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, 2000);
        //Auto focus - should keep that
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, Consts.aeMode);

        captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

        for(int i = 0; i < Consts.frameAmount; i++) {
            captureList.add(captureBuilder.build());
        }

        CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                           @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                mPictureCounter++;
                unlockFocus();
            }
        };

        mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
        mCaptureSession.captureBurst(captureList, CaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any thought?

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: Added the code to the main post

Comment: How did you get the result buffers?